# Android Background Task has any time limit?

Tags: android

Is there any time limit for Android background tasks?

Initially I ran a few repetitive commands in the main thread and it could be executed without any issue.

But when I moved the tasks to background tasks, it crashes after some time.

How do I remove the time limit for the background tasks?

I checked the logcat after it crashed, it is just showing "java.lang.RuntimeException: An Error has occured while executing doInBackground()"

Comment: It's probably because you're touching UI from your background task, but I agree with @adcom - you need to show the code

Comment: The other way around-  the main thread has a time limit in some functions.  Other threads never do.  If you have a crash, its not a watchdog its your code.

Comment: Do you want us to imagine your code and your error? Please do post some code so that one can clearly understand your problem and provide proper solution.

Comment: where is d logcat ? of that crash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background tasks do not have an expiration. However, if you are wanting tasks to run beyond the duration of your app activities, then you will need a Service.

After some time, your activity may be GC'd, so if your AsyncTask references the variables it will crash.